# get values to XML from multiple csv or text files

Tags: python, xml

I have a source.xml file, where I need to change some data in the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<component id="root" name="root">
    <component id="system" name="system">
        <param name="number_of_cores" value="2"/>
        <param name="number_of_L2s" value="4"/>
        <param name="number_of_L3s" value="0"/>
        <stat name="total_cycles" value="1600000000"/>
        <stat name="idle_cycles" value="0"/>
        <stat name="busy_cycles" value="1600000000"/>
        <!-- *********************** cores ******************* -->
        <component id="system.core0" name="core0">
            <!-- Core property -->
            <param name="clock_rate" value="1400"/>
            <param name="instruction_length" value="32"/>
            <param name="opcode_width" value="9"/>

            <param name="number_hardware_threads" value="4"/>

            <param name="fetch_width" value="1"/>

            <param name="number_instruction_fetch_ports" value="1"/>
            <param name="decode_width" value="1"/>
            <param name="issue_width" value="1"/>
            <param name="commit_width" value="1"/>
            <param name="fp_issue_width" value="1"/>
            <param name="prediction_width" value="0"/>
            <!-- number of branch instructions can be predicted simultannouesl-->
            <!-- Current version of McPAT does not distinguish int and floating point pipelines
            Theses parameters are reserved for future use.-->
            <param name="pipelines_per_core" value="1,1"/>
            <!--integer_pipeline and floating_pipelines, if the floating_pipelines is 0, then the pipeline is shared-->
            <param name="pipeline_depth" value="6,6"/>
            <!-- pipeline depth of int and fp, if pipeline is shared, the second number is the average cycles of fp ops -->
            <!-- issue and exe unit-->
            <param name="ALU_per_core" value="1"/>
            <!-- contains an adder, a shifter, and a logical unit -->
            <param name="MUL_per_core" value="1"/>
            <!-- For MUL and Div -->
            <param name="FPU_per_core" value="0.125"/>
            <!-- buffer between IF and ID stage -->
            <param name="instruction_buffer_size" value="16"/>
            <!-- buffer between ID and sche/exe stage -->
            <param name="decoded_stream_buffer_size" value="16"/>
            <param name="instruction_window_scheme" value="0"/>
            <!-- 0 PHYREG based, 1 RSBASED-->
            <!-- McPAT support 2 types of OoO cores, RS based and physical reg based-->
            <param name="instruction_window_size" value="16"/>
            <param name="fp_instruction_window_size" value="16"/>
            <!-- the instruction issue Q as in Alpha 21264; The RS as in Intel P6 -->
            <param name="ROB_size" value="80"/>
            <!-- each in-flight instruction has an entry in ROB -->
            <!-- registers -->
            <param name="archi_Regs_IRF_size" value="32"/>
            <param name="archi_Regs_FRF_size" value="32"/>
            <!--  if OoO processor, phy_reg number is needed for renaming logic,
            renaming logic is for both integer and floating point insts.  -->
            <param name="phy_Regs_IRF_size" value="80"/>
            <param name="phy_Regs_FRF_size" value="80"/>
            <!-- rename logic -->
            <param name="rename_scheme" value="0"/>
            <!-- can be RAM based(0) or CAM based(1) rename scheme
            RAM-based scheme will have free list, status table;
            CAM-based scheme have the valid bit in the data field of the CAM
            both RAM and CAM need RAM-based checkpoint table, checkpoint_depth=# of in_flight instructions;
            Detailed RAT Implementation see TR -->
            <param name="register_windows_size" value="8"/>
            <!-- how many windows in the windowed register file, sun processors;
            no register windowing is used when this number is 0 -->
            <!-- In OoO cores, loads and stores can be issued whether inorder(Pentium Pro) or (OoO)out-of-order(Alpha),
            They will always try to exeute out-of-order though. -->
            <param name="LSU_order" value="inorder"/>
            <param name="store_buffer_size" value="32"/>
            <!-- By default, in-order cores do not have load buffers -->
            <param name="load_buffer_size" value="32"/>
            <!-- number of ports refer to sustainable concurrent memory accesses -->
            <param name="memory_ports" value="1"/>
            <!-- max_allowed_in_flight_memo_instructions determins the # of ports of load and store buffer
            as well as the ports of Dcache which is connected to LSU -->
            <!-- dual-pumped Dcache can be used to save the extra read/write ports -->
            <param name="RAS_size" value="32"/>
            <!-- general stats, defines simulation periods;require total, idle, and busy cycles for senity check  -->
            <!-- please note: if target architecture is X86, then all the instrucions refer to (fused) micro-ops -->
            <stat name="total_instructions" value="10000000"/>
            <stat name="int_instructions" value="8000000"/>
            <stat name="fp_instructions" value="2000000"/>
            <stat name="branch_instructions" value="0"/>
            <stat name="branch_mispredictions" value="0"/>
            <stat name="load_instructions" value="100000"/>
            <stat name="store_instructions" value="100000"/>
            <stat name="committed_instructions" value="10000000"/>
            <stat name="committed_int_instructions" value="8000000"/>
            <stat name="committed_fp_instructions" value="200000"/>
            <stat name="pipeline_duty_cycle" value="0.6"/>
            <!--<=1, runtime_ipc/peak_ipc; averaged for all cores if homogenous -->
            <!-- the following cycle stats are used for heterogeneouse cores only,
                please ignore them if homogeneouse cores -->
            <stat name="total_cycles" value="100000"/>
            <stat name="idle_cycles" value="0"/>
            <stat name="busy_cycles" value="100000"/>
            <!-- instruction buffer stats -->
            <!-- ROB stats, both RS and Phy based OoOs have ROB
            performance simulator should capture the difference on accesses,
            otherwise, McPAT has to guess based on number of commited instructions. -->
            <stat name="ROB_reads" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="ROB_writes" value="263886"/>
            <!-- RAT accesses -->
            <stat name="rename_accesses" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="fp_rename_accesses" value="263886"/>
            <!-- decode and rename stage use this, should be total ic - nop -->
            <!-- Inst window stats -->
            <stat name="inst_window_reads" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="inst_window_writes" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="inst_window_wakeup_accesses" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="fp_inst_window_reads" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="fp_inst_window_writes" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="fp_inst_window_wakeup_accesses" value="263886"/>
            <!--  RF accesses -->
            <stat name="int_regfile_reads" value="1600000"/>
            <stat name="float_regfile_reads" value="40000"/>
            <stat name="int_regfile_writes" value="800000"/>
            <stat name="float_regfile_writes" value="20000"/>
            <!-- accesses to the working reg -->
            <stat name="function_calls" value="5"/>
            <stat name="context_switches" value="260343"/>
            <!-- Number of Windowes switches (number of function calls and returns)-->
            <!-- Alu stats by default, the processor has one FPU that includes the divider and
             multiplier. The fpu accesses should include accesses to multiplier and divider  -->
            <stat name="ialu_accesses" value="800000"/>
            <stat name="fpu_accesses" value="10000"/>
            <stat name="mul_accesses" value="100000"/>
            <stat name="cdb_alu_accesses" value="1000000"/>
            <stat name="cdb_mul_accesses" value="0"/>
            <stat name="cdb_fpu_accesses" value="0"/>
            <!-- multiple cycle accesses should be counted multiple times,
            otherwise, McPAT can use internal counter for different floating point instructions
            to get final accesses. But that needs detailed info for floating point inst mix -->
            <!--  currently the performance simulator should
            make sure all the numbers are final numbers,
            including the explicit read/write accesses,
            and the implicite accesses such as replacements and etc.
            Future versions of McPAT may be able to reason the implicite access
            based on param and stats of last level cache
            The same rule applies to all cache access stats too!  -->
            <!-- following is AF for max power computation.
                Do not change them, unless you understand them-->
            <stat name="IFU_duty_cycle" value="0.25"/>
            <stat name="LSU_duty_cycle" value="0.25"/>
            <stat name="MemManU_I_duty_cycle" value="1"/>
            <stat name="MemManU_D_duty_cycle" value="0.25"/>
            <stat name="ALU_duty_cycle" value="0.9"/>
            <stat name="MUL_duty_cycle" value="0.5"/>
            <stat name="FPU_duty_cycle" value="0.4"/>
            <stat name="ALU_cdb_duty_cycle" value="0.9"/>
            <stat name="MUL_cdb_duty_cycle" value="0.5"/>
            <stat name="FPU_cdb_duty_cycle" value="0.4"/>
            <component id="system.core0.predictor" name="PBT">
                <!-- branch predictor; tournament predictor see Alpha implementation -->
                <param name="local_predictor_size" value="10,3"/>
                <param name="local_predictor_entries" value="1024"/>
                <param name="global_predictor_entries" value="4096"/>
                <param name="global_predictor_bits" value="2"/>
                <param name="chooser_predictor_entries" value="4096"/>
                <param name="chooser_predictor_bits" value="2"/>
                <!-- These parameters can be combined like below in next version
                <param name="load_predictor" value="10,3,1024"/>
                <param name="global_predictor" value="4096,2"/>
                <param name="predictor_chooser" value="4096,2"/>
                -->
            </component>
            <component id="system.core0.itlb" name="itlb">
                <param name="number_entries" value="64"/>
                <stat name="total_accesses" value="800000"/>
                <stat name="total_misses" value="4"/>
                <stat name="conflicts" value="0"/>
                <!-- there is no write requests to itlb although writes happen to itlb after miss,
                which is actually a replacement -->
            </component>
            <component id="system.core0.icache" name="icache">
                <!-- there is no write requests to itlb although writes happen to it after miss,
                which is actually a replacement -->
                <param name="icache_config" value="16384,32,4,1,1,3,8,0"/>
                <!-- the parameters are capacity,block_width, associativity, bank, throughput w.r.t. core clock, latency w.r.t. core clock,output_width, cache policy -->
                <!-- cache_policy;//0 no write or write-though with non-write allocate;1 write-back with write-allocate -->
                <param name="buffer_sizes" value="16, 16, 16,0"/>
                <!-- cache controller buffer sizes: miss_buffer_size(MSHR),fill_buffer_size,prefetch_buffer_size,wb_buffer_size-->
                <stat name="read_accesses" value="200000"/>
                <stat name="read_misses" value="0"/>
                <stat name="conflicts" value="0"/>
            </component>
            <component id="system.core0.dtlb" name="dtlb">
                <param name="number_entries" value="64"/>
                <stat name="total_accesses" value="200000"/>
                <stat name="total_misses" value="4"/>
                <stat name="conflicts" value="0"/>
            </component>
            d
            <component id="system.core0.dcache" name="dcache">
                <!-- all the buffer related are optional -->
                <param name="dcache_config" value="8192,16,4,1,1,3,16,0"/>
                <param name="buffer_sizes" value="16, 16, 16, 16"/>
                <!-- cache controller buffer sizes: miss_buffer_size(MSHR),fill_buffer_size,prefetch_buffer_size,wb_buffer_size-->
                <stat name="read_accesses" value="200000"/>
                <stat name="write_accesses" value="27276"/>
                <stat name="read_misses" value="1632"/>
                <stat name="write_misses" value="183"/>
                <stat name="conflicts" value="0"/>
            </component>
            <component id="system.core0.BTB" name="BTB">
                <!-- all the buffer related are optional -->
                <param name="BTB_config" value="8192,4,2,1, 1,3"/>
                <!-- the parameters are capacity,block_width,associativity,bank, throughput w.r.t. core clock, latency w.r.t. core clock,-->
            </component>
        </component>


        <!-- Core1 -->

        <component id="system.core1" name="core1">
            <!-- Core property -->
            <param name="clock_rate" value="1400"/>
            <param name="instruction_length" value="32"/>
            <param name="opcode_width" value="9"/>
            <param name="machine_type" value="1"/>
            <param name="number_hardware_threads" value="4"/>

            <param name="fetch_width" value="1"/>

            <param name="number_instruction_fetch_ports" value="1"/>
            <param name="decode_width" value="1"/>

            <param name="issue_width" value="1"/>

            <param name="commit_width" value="1"/>

            <param name="fp_issue_width" value="1"/>
            <param name="prediction_width" value="0"/>


            <param name="pipelines_per_core" value="1,1"/>

            <param name="pipeline_depth" value="6,6"/>

            <param name="ALU_per_core" value="1"/>

            <param name="MUL_per_core" value="1"/>

            <param name="FPU_per_core" value="0.125"/>
            <!-- buffer between IF and ID stage -->
            <param name="instruction_buffer_size" value="16"/>
            <!-- buffer between ID and sche/exe stage -->
            <param name="decoded_stream_buffer_size" value="16"/>
            <param name="instruction_window_scheme" value="0"/>
            <!-- 0 PHYREG based, 1 RSBASED-->
            <!-- McPAT support 2 types of OoO cores, RS based and physical reg based-->
            <param name="instruction_window_size" value="16"/>
            <param name="fp_instruction_window_size" value="16"/>
            <!-- the instruction issue Q as in Alpha 21264; The RS as in Intel P6 -->
            <param name="ROB_size" value="80"/>
            <!-- each in-flight instruction has an entry in ROB -->
            <!-- registers -->
            <param name="archi_Regs_IRF_size" value="32"/>
            <param name="archi_Regs_FRF_size" value="32"/>
            <!--  if OoO processor, phy_reg number is needed for renaming logic,
            renaming logic is for both integer and floating point insts.  -->
            <param name="phy_Regs_IRF_size" value="80"/>
            <param name="phy_Regs_FRF_size" value="80"/>
            <!-- rename logic -->
            <param name="rename_scheme" value="0"/>

            <param name="register_windows_size" value="8"/>

            <param name="LSU_order" value="inorder"/>
            <param name="store_buffer_size" value="32"/>
            <!-- By default, in-order cores do not have load buffers -->
            <param name="load_buffer_size" value="32"/>

            <param name="memory_ports" value="1"/>

            <param name="RAS_size" value="32"/>


            <stat name="total_instructions" value="10000000"/>
            <stat name="int_instructions" value="8000000"/>
            <stat name="fp_instructions" value="2000000"/>
            <stat name="branch_instructions" value="0"/>
            <stat name="branch_mispredictions" value="0"/>
            <stat name="load_instructions" value="100000"/>
            <stat name="store_instructions" value="100000"/>
            <stat name="committed_instructions" value="10000000"/>
            <stat name="committed_int_instructions" value="8000000"/>
            <stat name="committed_fp_instructions" value="200000"/>
            <stat name="pipeline_duty_cycle" value="0.6"/>

            <!-- the following cycle stats are used for heterogeneouse cores only,
                please ignore them if homogeneouse cores -->
            <stat name="total_cycles" value="100000"/>
            <stat name="idle_cycles" value="0"/>
            <stat name="busy_cycles" value="100000"/>
            <!-- instruction buffer stats -->

            <stat name="ROB_reads" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="ROB_writes" value="263886"/>
            <!-- RAT accesses -->
            <stat name="rename_accesses" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="fp_rename_accesses" value="263886"/>

            <!-- Inst window stats -->
            <stat name="inst_window_reads" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="inst_window_writes" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="inst_window_wakeup_accesses" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="fp_inst_window_reads" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="fp_inst_window_writes" value="263886"/>
            <stat name="fp_inst_window_wakeup_accesses" value="263886"/>
            <!--  RF accesses -->
            <stat name="int_regfile_reads" value="1600000"/>
            <stat name="float_regfile_reads" value="40000"/>
            <stat name="int_regfile_writes" value="800000"/>
            <stat name="float_regfile_writes" value="20000"/>
            <!-- accesses to the working reg -->
            <stat name="function_calls" value="5"/>
            <stat name="context_switches" value="260343"/>

            <!-- Alu stats by default, the processor has one FPU that includes the divider and
             multiplier. The fpu accesses should include accesses to multiplier and divider  -->
            <stat name="ialu_accesses" value="800000"/>
            <stat name="fpu_accesses" value="10000"/>
            <stat name="mul_accesses" value="100000"/>
            <stat name="cdb_alu_accesses" value="1000000"/>
            <stat name="cdb_mul_accesses" value="0"/>
            <stat name="cdb_fpu_accesses" value="0"/>
            <!-- multiple cycle accesses should be counted multiple times,
            otherwise, McPAT can use internal counter for different floating point instructions
            to get final accesses. But that needs detailed info for floating point inst mix -->

            <!-- following is AF for max power computation.
                Do not change them, unless you understand them-->
            <stat name="IFU_duty_cycle" value="0.25"/>
            <stat name="LSU_duty_cycle" value="0.25"/>
            <stat name="MemManU_I_duty_cycle" value="1"/>
            <stat name="MemManU_D_duty_cycle" value="0.25"/>
            <stat name="ALU_duty_cycle" value="0.9"/>
            <stat name="MUL_duty_cycle" value="0.5"/>
            <stat name="FPU_duty_cycle" value="0.4"/>
            <stat name="ALU_cdb_duty_cycle" value="0.9"/>
            <stat name="MUL_cdb_duty_cycle" value="0.5"/>
            <stat name="FPU_cdb_duty_cycle" value="0.4"/>
            <component id="system.core1.predictor" name="PBT">
                <!-- branch predictor; tournament predictor see Alpha implementation -->
                <param name="local_predictor_size" value="10,3"/>
                <param name="local_predictor_entries" value="1024"/>
                <param name="global_predictor_entries" value="4096"/>
                <param name="global_predictor_bits" value="2"/>
                <param name="chooser_predictor_entries" value="4096"/>
                <param name="chooser_predictor_bits" value="2"/>
                <!-- These parameters can be combined like below in next version
                <param name="load_predictor" value="10,3,1024"/>
                <param name="global_predictor" value="4096,2"/>
                <param name="predictor_chooser" value="4096,2"/>
                -->
            </component>
            <component id="system.core1.itlb" name="itlb">
                <param name="number_entries" value="64"/>
                <stat name="total_accesses" value="800000"/>
                <stat name="total_misses" value="4"/>
                <stat name="conflicts" value="0"/>
                <!-- there is no write requests to itlb although writes happen to itlb after miss,
                which is actually a replacement -->
            </component>
            <component id="system.core1.icache" name="icache">
                <!-- there is no write requests to itlb although writes happen to it after miss,
                which is actually a replacement -->
                <param name="icache_config" value="16384,32,4,1,1,3,8,0"/>
                <!-- the parameters are capacity,block_width, associativity, bank, throughput w.r.t. core clock, latency w.r.t. core clock,output_width, cache policy -->
                <!-- cache_policy;//0 no write or write-though with non-write allocate;1 write-back with write-allocate -->
                <param name="buffer_sizes" value="16, 16, 16,0"/>
                <!-- cache controller buffer sizes: miss_buffer_size(MSHR),fill_buffer_size,prefetch_buffer_size,wb_buffer_size-->
                <stat name="read_accesses" value="200000"/>
                <stat name="read_misses" value="0"/>
                <stat name="conflicts" value="0"/>
            </component>
            <component id="system.core1.dtlb" name="dtlb">
                <param name="number_entries" value="64"/>
                <stat name="total_accesses" value="200000"/>
                <stat name="total_misses" value="4"/>
                <stat name="conflicts" value="0"/>
            </component>
            d
            <component id="system.core1.dcache" name="dcache">
                <!-- all the buffer related are optional -->
                <param name="dcache_config" value="8192,16,4,1,1,3,16,0"/>
                <param name="buffer_sizes" value="16, 16, 16, 16"/>
                <!-- cache controller buffer sizes: miss_buffer_size(MSHR),fill_buffer_size,prefetch_buffer_size,wb_buffer_size-->
                <stat name="read_accesses" value="200000"/>
                <stat name="write_accesses" value="27276"/>
                <stat name="read_misses" value="1632"/>
                <stat name="write_misses" value="183"/>
                <stat name="conflicts" value="0"/>
            </component>
            <component id="system.core1.BTB" name="BTB">
                <!-- all the buffer related are optional -->
                <param name="BTB_config" value="8192,4,2,1, 1,3"/>
                <!-- the parameters are capacity,block_width,associativity,bank, throughput w.r.t. core clock, latency w.r.t. core clock,-->
            </component>
        </component>
```

I have 2 text files containing numbers name core-0.txt and core-1.txt.
I need to read data from this text file and take the data corresponding to the "system.core0" block and "system.core1" block. 
here are the "stat" I want to change in each "system.core{}" block:

```
<stat name="total_instructions" value="10000000"/>
<stat name="int_instructions" value="8000000"/>
<stat name="fp_instructions" value="2000000"/>
<stat name="branch_instructions" value="0"/>
<stat name="branch_mispredictions" value="0"/>
```

In the text files I have 200 rows.
So I want to generate 200 xml files with the updated data coming from the text files.
sample of text file core0.txt:

```
2.64E+08    2.64E+08    1.58E+08    1.51E+08    7.85E+06
1.68E+07    1.68E+07    1.01E+07    8.95E+06    1.15E+06
8.96E+08    8.96E+08    5.38E+08    5.32E+08    5.45E+06
9.14E+08    9.14E+08    5.48E+08    5.28E+08    2.00E+07
1.86E+09    1.86E+09    1.11E+09    1.10E+09    1.75E+07
5.12E+08    5.12E+08    3.07E+08    2.86E+08    2.12E+07
1.08E+08    1.08E+08    6.47E+07    4.11E+07    2.36E+07
1.04E+08    1.04E+08    6.24E+07    3.98E+07    2.26E+07
1.65E+09    1.65E+09    9.92E+08    9.69E+08    2.27E+07
7.84E+08    7.84E+08    4.70E+08    4.61E+08    9.59E+06
```

core-1.txt

```
8.71E+06    8.71E+06    5.22E+06    5.22E+06    5.41E+03
9.57E+08    9.57E+08    5.74E+08    5.72E+08    1.90E+06
2.76E+08    2.76E+08    1.66E+08    1.62E+08    3.92E+06
8.62E+08    8.62E+08    5.17E+08    5.02E+08    1.49E+07
1.72E+09    1.72E+09    1.03E+09    1.01E+09    2.02E+07
3.71E+08    3.71E+08    2.23E+08    2.00E+08    2.30E+07
9.42E+07    9.42E+07    5.65E+07    3.46E+07    2.19E+07
1.01E+08    1.01E+08    6.07E+07    3.51E+07    2.55E+07
1.67E+09    1.67E+09    1.00E+09    9.83E+08    2.11E+07
```

I am not sure how to pass data from multiple files at the same time in python.

Comment: the above xml is one file and you would you like to generate 200 xml files ?

Comment: yes...basically make copy of this xml 200 time with the new value in the mentioned "system.core0" and "system.core1" block

Comment: could you give a format like how each xml file should look like including blocks in the question

Comment: I am not sure I understood you correctly, but the new xmls would be just the same, except for the above mentioned attributes, the other values in the xmls would be unchanged. 
format of the text file is 5 columns (each column representing the variable attirbute in question respectively) and 200 rows.

Comment: okay so you have n text files which needs to parse data from n text files with the names"total_instructions", "int_instructions", "fp_instructions", "branch_instructions", "branch_misprediction" with different values say 200 different values into 200 xml files ...correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: yup, thats is right.

Comment: could you give a contents of .txt files which has the data in the question

Comment: @Praneeth, 
Just edited the original post with the input data.